# IIS: "The resource cannot be found" over https, but everything works fine over http

Tags: iis

I am configuring a REST Service using IIS, and everything works fine over http.  However, when I switch to https, I see:

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.`
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    The resource cannot be found. 
    Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
    dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily 
    unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled
    correctly. 

    Requested URL: /SiteName/ServiceName.svc/1

    Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3620; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3618
```

I'm new to IIS and have no idea what the problem could be.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What version of IIS?

Comment: 6 Maybe?  I'm on Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, but for a completely different issue.  Make sure you compile your site before deploying it.  I had some pages that were compiled and some pages that were not compiled.

It took me so long to figure out because when I tried viewing these pages on the application server (Windows Server 2008), it wouldn't let me view a non secure page (http protocol), because of Internet Explorer's security settings.  I only had a binding for port 80 when testing on a browser on the server box.  So I couldn't even see the aspx page that was compiled, let alone the aspx pages that were not compiled.  A plain HTML page was visible on both boxes however, on the same site--that part was interesting.  When I viewed the pages on another machine (running Windows 7) on that network, the compiled aspx page showed up fine because it was compiled.  And the non-compiled pages did not.

Long answer on another site:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547217/am-running-the-web-allication-using-asp-net-am-getting-this-error/14866462#14866462

Answer (score 1):

When http and https respond differently, it's usually a binding issue.

Check your bindings in the site properties to ensure that you have the same bindings for http and https on your site.  Also, IPv6 can come into play sometimes, causing your bindings to not respond as you would assume.  A good way to test is by IP rather than host name.  If it doesn't throw the same 404 then you know that you have an IPv6 binding issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Common name" attribute of SSL certificate. It should match the server name in your URL.